# Strtok_r returning NULL

Tags: c, rpc

I'm trying to tokenize a string taken from a file. strtok_r works properly on the first sub string and then returns null (and segmentation fault cause I try to strndup into an other var)

```c
char buffer[500];
char * c;
char * c1;
char * c2;
//....
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), f) != NULL){
    c2 = buffer;
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    c = strtok(c2, ":");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        c = strtok(NULL, ":");
        printf("%s\n", c);
    }
    if(strcmp(c, argp->origen) == 0){
        c = strtok(NULL, ":");
        printf("%s\n", c);
        if(strcmp(c, argp->destino) == 0){
            nodo = malloc(sizeof(lista_vuelo));
            c2 = buffer;

            c = strtok_r(c2, ":", &c1); 
            nodo->IdReg = atoi(c);
            printf("\n%d test\n", nodo->IdReg); //Works until here

            c = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &c1);
            printf("\n%s\n", c); //Prints null and then segmentation fault

            nodo->Idvuelo = strndup(c, strlen(c));
            printf("\n%s\n", nodo->Idvuelo);
//....
```

> Input from file :

3:IBE3674:02-04-2019:19-45:Madrid:Berlin:Barajas:Tegel:IBERIA:210:35:6:T4:60:N

> Output :

3 test -> Expected output

```
(null)
Violación de segmento (`core' generado) -> Segmentation fault, (null) should be IBE3674
```

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: @Yastanub It's reading from a file, the input is 3:IBE3674:02-04-2019:19-45:Madrid:Berlin:Barajas:Tegel:IBERIA:210:35:6:T4:60:N // Will add it to the main post

Comment: What do you expect strtok to return and why?

Comment: Pointer to the next token so I can add it into a char pointer contained in a struct

Comment: Well, if `strtok` returns `NULL` and afterwards your program crashes, you should think about checking the return value before using the `NULL` pointer. If you already pass `NULL` into `printf` you invoke undefined behaviour. Afterwards you still ignore the `NULL` and feed the pointer into `strlen` and `strndup`. A crash is not surprising if you feed `NULL` into tons of functions that are not expecting it

Comment: @Gerhardh Yeah, I know the crash is not surprising cause I know there is a null before, was more about the strtok returning null, thanks!

Comment: I see. Maybe for future questions you put the things in the title that are not already clear for you.

Comment: You are totally right, will do it and sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtok` does not simply modify the pointer it is passed but actually the string itself. It replaces each found delimiter with a `null` character.

If you had string `test:strtok:for:me` and call `strtok` once you had `test\0strtok:for:me` after that.

So when you iterate ofer the first couple tokens each `:` is replaced with `\0`. If you now reset your pointer `c2` to the beginning of the string and call strtok again, strtok finds a `null` charakter before it finds a delimiter and assumes the string ended before a delimiter is found and returns `NULL`.

Comment: So, I should make a copy of buffer into c2 and not just assign the pointer, right? Yeah, it worked, thanks you very much

Comment: @Opresor that would be one possibility but then you had the same string 2 times in memory(almost at least). You could also save the first tokens into an array and then reuse them later. Also note that strtok does not create new strings but only replaces the delimiters by 0 and then returns a pointer to the beginning of the token. So you actual string is not really split but just segmented. If you delete the Initial string, all tokens are invalidated.